# Cannot add network folder to media library

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, network-shares, media

I have a network drive (wd livebook), I cannot include a folder on it within media libary because it says it is not indexed.

To index it I tried to add system to users authorization, but each time I add system after clicking apply it is removed.

What is weird is that I have one folder which has been added to media library successfully I don't know how I guess it's when I plug my windows phone I have added that folder. But this folder has same properties as the other I cannot add to media library by myself.

How to really do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Tool Win Library Tool to add network folders to a library:

**Win Library Tool**

> Windows libraries (introduced in Windows 7) could have been a really useful feature of 
>   Windows, however unfortunately they arrived in a slighly cut-down form
>   out of the box.  Microsoft decided against exposing some really useful
>   capabilities to users, like adding network locations, pretty much the
>   first thing I tried to do.  You get this message:
>
> [image]
>
> Luckily, you can add network locations (and any other un-indexed
>   locations), but it must be done programatically.  MS supply a command
>   line utility slutil.exe, candidate for the worst named executable in
>   history.  Pretty sure it stands for shell_library_util.  Anyway, I
>   decided to write a tool to make it easy to add network locations, and
>   added a few other features as well:
>
> ```
> Add network (UNC or mapped drive) and any other un-indexed folders to libraries.
>
> Backup library configuration, such that a saved set of libraries can be instantly restored at any point (like after a re-install of the
> ```
>
> OS or for transfer between multiple computers).
>
> ```
> Create a mirror of all libraries (using symbolic links) in [SystemDrive]:\libraries.  This means you can reference all your files
> ```
>
> using a much shorter path, and also provides another entry-point to
>   your files in many places in the Operating System (e.g. file open/save
>   dialogs).
>
> ```
> Change a library’s icon.
> ```
>
> [image]

**Download:**

http://zornsoftware.codenature.info/blog/win7-library-tool.html